# Is it possible to measure frequency upto 500Mhz with 50Mhz oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, high-frequency, frequency-measurement

Is there a way to measure higher frequency measurements with a 50 MHz oscilloscope (eg rigol ds1054z)? Perhaps some post processing of captured waveforms? Or with the help of some adapters?

I have a Rigol DSO1504z digital oscilloscope.
Link. http://www.scientechworld.com/test-and-measurement-solutions/digital-oscilloscopes/50mhz-digital-oscilloscope-ds1054z

Comment: You might also get more specific answers if you describe where your signal comes from, what it is etc.

Comment: A key question here is what properties you need to measure.  If you literally mean frequency, something like a frequency counter could work.  Another interesting gadget is an RTL-SDR dongle.  The accuracy of any of these of course depends on their internal clocks/oscillators.   Also beware with the RTL-SDR that internal distortion can replicate a signal at many places across the band if you are not careful to set the attenuation appropriately.

Comment: @Chris Stratton, Well basically I just don't want to spend huge sum of money on buying expensive oscilloscope with higher bandwidth, I would like to measure all or most of the characteristics of a high frequency waveform that I can measure with the low end oscilloscope with the help of some additional circuitry or/and with the help of my PC.      Ex my rigol cost me around 400$, what if I can spend another 100-300$ for an adapter that helps me work with higher frequency. Maybe make use of my old motherboard/CPU lying around. Or make use of some circuitry of me current PC or with some software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Included mostly for interest, as this is not a beginner project.

There's a way, but it's not all that simple. Build [a sampling front end for an oscilloscope](http://www.redrok.com/Circuits_1GHz-samplig-Oscilloscope-Front-End.pdf).

[image]

The above circuit will allow **periodic** signals with 1GHz bandwidth to be measured on a 10MHz or better analog oscilloscope. It's no good for one-shot signals.

Answer (score 6):

Not really. 500MHz is too far above the nominal bandwidth for any aliasing frequencies to get through to the digitiser within it.

You can use your scope as a 'back end' for two different types of front end.

The first is a heterodyne downconverting mixer. You would need a local oscillator, close to 500MHz, and a mixer. The scope would measure the IF, the difference between the LO and the input. It would show you the amplitude of the fundamental of the input waveform as well, sufficiently well to measure it.

The second is a digital divider. Prescalers are fairly inexpensive and obtainable, a /16 would get 500MHz down to 31MHz. It would tell you nothing about the amplitude, except whether it was enough to clock the divider or not.

A lower cost alternative to the simple LO and mixer would be a harmonic mixer. This would allow for a lower frequency LO, but there's more potential for unwanted products to get through to the IF.

Because all of these methods throw away or confuse some information about the input signal, you need to be more careful about interpretting what you see in the IF. Other input signal frequencies will confuse the output, and differently depending on whether they're harmonically or non-harmonically related, and bigger or smaller than the wanted signal. A bandpass filter at 500MHz could be a useful investment.

That last paragraph seems quite vague. It's like this. If you know what I'm talking about, then you don't need any more detail. If you don't, then there's no way you can be brought up to speed on what to look out for in the space of an answer here. Look up superheterodyne, intermodulation, and 'how a spectrum analyser works'.

Comment: I was about to write the same answer, but luckily you were faster! Please do also point out that mixing down only works for bandpass signals: If OP has a signal that has spectral components "somewhere between 0 and 500 MHz", this doesn't help.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There are [compressive sensing techniques](http://webee.technion.ac.il/Sites/People/YoninaEldar/Info/mainFormat.pdf) that depend on the actual bandwidth of the signal and not on the bandwidth range considered. For example, if you had a 100KHz signal "somewhere" in a 1GHz range, it could be isolated while doing the processing at far less than 1GHz. That said, the techniques are fairly sophisticated and probably not practical for this use case.

Comment: @Derek compressive sensing would require the analog frontend to still let through the frequencies with signal on them :) but yes, you could, given suitable spectral signal location maybe do something like a multi-tone superhet and decompose that with compressive sensing methods...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Of course. What I was suggesting would still require some heterodyne-like front-end. The benefit is merely that you wouldn't have to know and "tune" it to the correct frequency band. (Where these techniques are more valuable is when you have a *multi-band* signal. You could capture all of them simultaneously no matter how spread out in the frequency range they were, as long as the total bandwidth of all the bands was less that the processing rate.)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the sampling-scope bandwidth.

When I first encountered a digital-scope, I wanted to explore the "aliasing". In that lab was a digital-NTSC-RF-generator (a fine beast from Phillips), and I set it to 1HZ faster than the scope's sampling rate of 200MHz. Indeed we saw a beat note on the scope's digital display of 1Hz.

Thus you may be able to down-convert from 500MHz to some lower rate. Try it.

Comment: While I do encourage just trying it and seeing what happens, there's a big difference between being 1Hz into the aliasing filter roll-off and being 450MHz beyond the nominal cutoff.